# How to compute quintinomial coefficients?

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients, multinomial-coefficients, project-euler

I'm looking for a way to compute elements of a quintinomial triangle.

Is there a general case?

To be more specific I'm looking for a way to compute the coefficients of the polynomial $(x^4 + x^3 + x^2 +x + 1)^n $ , $\forall x\in\Bbb R , \forall n \in \Bbb N$ for consecutive values of n.

I'm working on project Euler problem 588.

Comment: you can also refer to [this OEIS section](http://oeis.org/A035343)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a derivation of  an  expression which could be  implemented. We use  the *coefficient   of* operator $[x^p]$ to denote the coefficient  of $x^p$  in  a series.

> We obtain
>   \begin{align*}
> [x^p]&(x^4+x^3+x^2+x+1)^n\\
> &=[x^p]\left(\frac{1-x^5}{1-x}\right)^n\tag{1}\\
> &=[x^p](1-x^5)^n\sum_{k=0}^\infty\binom{-n}{k}(-x)^k\tag{2}\\
> &=[x^p]\sum_{j=0}^n\binom{n}{j}\left(-x^5\right)^j\sum_{k=0}^\infty\binom{n+k-1}{k}x^k\tag{3}\\
> &=\sum_{j=0}^{\min\{n,\lfloor{p/5}\rfloor\}}\binom{n}{j}(-1)^j[x^{p-5j}]\sum_{k=0}^\infty\binom{n+k-1}{k}x^k\tag{4}\\
> &=\sum_{j=0}^{\min\{n,\lfloor{p/5}\rfloor\}}(-1)^j\binom{n}{j}\binom{n+p-5j-1}{p-5j}\tag{5}
> \end{align*}

*Comment:*

- In  (1) we apply the formula of the *[finite geometric series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series#Formula)*.
- In (2) we apply the *[binomial series expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_series)* of $(1-x)^{-n}$.
- In (3) we use the identity $\binom{-p}{q}=\binom{p+q-1}{q}(-1)^q$.
- In (4) we use the linearity of the *coefficient of* operator  and use the rule $$[x^p]x^qA(x)=[x^{p-q}]A(x)$$ We also restrict the upper limit of the sum, since the exponent of $x^{p-5j}$ has to be non-negative.
- In (5) we select the coefficient of $x^{p-5j}$.